# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity - Id from inherited class

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have following classes:

```
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners({ BaseEntityListener.class})
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID", length = 16)
    protected String objectId;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVE", length = 1)
    private boolean status = true;

}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@AttributeOverride(name = "objectId", column = @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false))
public class A extends BaseEntity {

    @Id 
    @Column(name = "OBJECT_ID")
    private String objectId;


    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;
}
```

As You can see, i'm trying to use field objectId inherited from BaseEntity as an ID.
During application startup, there goes an error of 
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity app.jpa.model.A

How can I fix this?
Hibernate 5.28

Answer (score 0):

How about making the BaseEntity Abstract:

public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {